# SharePoint and OOS Logs

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I and new to SharePoint and Office Online Server have some enquiries on the logs. I know that the logs can be found at the usual Hive folder, do any of the logs contain information such as the following:

1. Application Configuration Changes
2. Application Security Policies and Configuration Changes
3. Application Account and access rights creation and changes
4. Failed login attempts (user or admin)

I have found some documentation on SharePoint and learnt that Administration Actions covers some parts of the information required, but are there any other logs that can provide the information required above?

Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you specified Office Online Server, it seems that you're meant SharePoint On-premises (SP Server), not SP Online?
It is a broad scope of changes that you've specified.
Nevertheless it it worth trying:

1. Yes, Administrative Actions could help.
2. It is not clear, what is the *Security policy* in terms of SharePoint, but probably it could be also covered by Administrative Actions.
3. Accounts are not created in SharePoint Server itself. Changes of access permissions on SP sites can be monitored with [Audit log reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527) (that needs to be configured first, obviously).
4. Usually Windows Event [Security logs auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-logon-events) are used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was referring to both, SP server and OOS physical server. Administrative Actions had been helpful, but it does not really cover much. For Audit Logs reports, does it show up in the logs folder with the other logs?

Comment: Audit logs are generated on demand. You should go to `Site settings - Site collection administration - Audit log reports` and then choose one of the pre-defined templates or create your custom report, for instance: _permission changes events in specific period on specific libraries_ and so on.. The problem is that they still need to be correctly interpreted: they are not in manager-friendly-format )

Comment: Oh I see, in this case they can only be viewed on in site collection? Lets say if I generated out the report, it is a downloadable file? Or can we set a path?

Comment: It is better to just try out this once by yourself. You should specify site library to which this file will be saved after generating. Also, at `Site Collection Audit Settings - Audit Log Trimming` section you can specify the settings to generate and keep those reports in specific site library over periods of time.